Is the assumption of a "purely rational voter" a fundamental flaw in Allan Lichtman’s 13 Keys model for predicting presidential elections in the USA?
Prof. Allan Lichtman said in Chris Cuomo´s NewsNation “The premise of the 13 keys is that a rational, pragmatic electorate decides whether the White House party has governed well enough to deserve four more years.”
To achieve more accurate predictions, should the core premise (a rational electorate) be revised to better account for the complexities of human behavior? After all, human decision-making is influenced by more than just rationality; it involves biases, emotions, and subconscious factors, that cannot be ignored.
Reference:
Cuomo, Chris. “Allan Lichtman Explains What Went Wrong with Presidential Prediction.” NewsNation, YouTube.

"To achieve more accurate predictions, should the core premise (a rational electorate) be revised to better account for the complexities of human behavior?" Yes. But it isn't entire clear what more of an answer you want.

It would be nice to link to the original premise of the 13 keys rational voter in a definition somewhere.  As it is it is hard to see if it is flawed or not, without knowing the original premise.  FWIW, similar theories have been making ground for years in investor economics:  the notion that the market and/or individual economic actors are always rational is also getting some structured pushback as an oversimplification of actual market dynamics.  https://mises.org/misesian/homo-economicus-myth

This Q effectively asks how a model in social science can be improved upon. This is too broad and opinion-based a Q for this site.

It's one of the many fundamental flaws. I'm sure there are more in these 13 keys. In general it's impossible to always correctly predict the future.

We would have to know what this person thinks is a rational electorate, at the very least. Does a rational voter always vote for what will make them more money? That surely can explain a lot of voting, but not most of those wealthy people who vote for wealth redistribution or poorer people who vote against social welfare. Does a rational voter always vote for the candidate who will support the policies that they prefer? Then how can any voter ever be disappointed in their candidates' policies? Perhaps they only vote for the candidate whose policies they believe they will prefer?

That may be true, but it's unclear to what extent it can helpfully be described as rational or will have much use in predicting or understanding election results.

Particularly since (seemingly?) rational reasoning can actually theoretically produce profit-minimizing behavior that is usually not observed in reality.

The very meaning of "rationality" is a politically contestable term, often driven by questionable assumptions about what people's goals are - typically assumptions that are already falsified and known to be inconsistent with evidence.

Afai can see that list already includes whether people are "charismatic", whether they are incumbent, whether there are long term or short term ups in the economy, whether they ran uncontested and so on. So it's not as if those were devoid of biases and emotions to begin with.

Does every "rational"  voter have access to the same data and has the same level of understanding of that data? If not, then they may come to different conclusions.

@doneal24 I presume a "rational voter" in their books is someone making decisions that best benefit their economic situation and that they have full information of what is publicly accessible about that.  Which yeah isn't the only metric by which you can make voting decisions. Like just add families and you might have more than 1 perspective to account for and if you add other factors outside the economic you can get even more complicated. Also yes despite openly accessible information people might still not have the time or ability to access them and so the available data might be different.

Indeed, Daniel Kahneman has received a Nobel Memorial Prize in Economic Sciences for demonstrating how seemingly rational people are actually acting irrationally - amending economic theories, which often took for granted that the market actors act rationally.
There is however a bigger elephant in the room - the imperfect information and qualifications of the voters. Indeed, hardly any voter reads all the relevant legislation that their representatives in the Congress vote for or against. One could even argue that it is physically impossible (we are talking about hundred pages volumes of technical/legal language.) And even when they try, they hardly can understand much, not having expertise in economics, law, military, etc.
I dare to make even more striking claim: very few voters actually seriously study the media, mostly limiting their sources to watching a couple of TV programs and/or a few news sites and blogs. And those  chosen are likely catering to their already existing views.
Lichtman's use of term rational is however more limited:

Why did he think Harris would win, and what went wrong? “The keys are premised on the proposition that a rational, pragmatic electorate decides whether the White House party has governed well enough to get another four years,” he explains. “Just as this kind of hate and violence is new, there are precedent-shattering elements now to our political system, most notably disinformation.

This kind of rationality assumption is not necessarily - obviously, most Democrats would say that Biden governed "well enough", but it is just as likely that most Trump voters do not think so, and we do not have an objective criteria to decide which of them is right (or we wouldn't need elections in the first place.)

The problem with Lictman is that he's using the word "rational" to mean: people that think like me and watch the same media.

@SurpriseDog And then Lichtman trots out "disinformation" as his lame excuse.  Nate Silver destroys Lichtman here - calling his work "junk science" and "subjective" - all the way to including examples of Lichtman dissembling and waffling between predicting the electoral college or the popular vote.
